# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

[image]

When I opened Web Developer in Firefox:

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list
>
> note: { opened at line 7, column 7

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image, post it as text instead. Images are not compatible with clipboards, screen-readers and search-engines, and they make it harder for people to help you. Would you edit your question? A code formatting tool is available.

Comment: Look at the end of your code, you have two characters switched, voting to close as typo

Comment: Why do your title and your question body include two totally different and unrelated error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Line 17 should be `});`, and not `)};`

Comment: Questions resolved by fixing a typo should be vote closed, not answered